# Fernflower Java decompiler help

Tags: java, decompiling

As the author has forgotten to add a detailed usage listing (or I can't find it), I wonder if anyone knows anything about the command-line options accepted by the FernFlower decompiler application.

You can find an online version here: http://www.reversed-java.com/fernflower/
I'm trying to enable/disable all these flags that are present on that webpage.

The actual command-line JAR can be found here: https://github.com/Bukkit/Bukkit-MinecraftServer

Many thanks
Nik

Comment: Here is README for FF http://pastebin.com/BbfP9tWf

Comment: Both of those links do not work anymore. I previously used the  http://www.reversed-java.com/fernflower/ website to decompile but when I use the command-line JAR it fails to return the same results. In fact the decompiled source is not usable at all. Any thoughts on how to make it work like the website?

Comment: https://github.com/Bukkit/Bukkit-MinecraftServer gives me error 404

Comment: MCP stands for Mod Coder Pack

Comment: Updated URLs: http://mcpold.ocean-labs.de/index.php/MCP_Releases and https://hub.spigotmc.org/stash/projects/SPIGOT/repos/builddata/browse/bin

Answer (score 49):

> > As the author has forgotten to add a detailed usage listing

No, I haven't :) See readme.txt in your jar for the full documentation.

Comment: your site is down though. any chance to get fernflower from you?

Comment: @Stiver, I've got to second flying sheep's request. Or perhaps any chance of the above-mentioned www.reversed-java.com/fernflower/ coming back online? You're such a tease showing off this amazing tool and then taking it away again. :) Sincerely hope you'll get the chance to keep up the great work.

Comment: Stiver, would you mind posting hashes for your releases? That way we can tell if a copy we find is legitimate.

Comment: @Anonymoose download MCP ("Minecraft Coder's Pack") for Minecraft; it includes a legit copy of Fernflower.

Comment: @Sukasa: and how can we know it's legit?

Comment: you know it's legit when you download it from the MCP site.

Answer (score 5):

Current source code and documentation of Fernflower is available here: https://github.com/fesh0r/fernflower

Command line options are listed there, I do not copy-paste them from github.

Online version of Fernflower is now available on this site:
http://www.javadecompilers.com/